# On two Cauchy sequences in an incomplete metric space:

Tags: real-analysis

If my title's two Cauchy sequences are used to construct a sequence of their distances, $d(a_n,b_n)$,  is this a Cauchy sequence and does it converge?  I have tried to use the "reverse triangle inequality" but did not get very far.  The two sequences are not equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the (quadrilateral-)inequality $\vert d(x,y)-d(x',y')\vert\leq d(x,x')+d(y,y')$, which follows almost immediately from the triangle inequality, for $x=a_n, x'=a_m, y=b_n, y'=b_m$.

Answer (score 1):

It is Cauchy. Use the estimates
$$d(a_n, b_n) \leq d(a_n, a_m) + d(a_m, b_m) + d(b_m, b_n)$$
$$d(a_m, b_m) \leq d(a_m, a_n) + d(a_n, b_n) + d(b_n, b_m)$$